# What was the first Hentai ever made?

Tags: anime-history, manga-history

I just want to ask what is the first Hentai manga and what is the first Hentai anime?

Comment: The first hentai manga depends on what exactly qualifies as a manga. Pornographic drawings have been made in Japan since the Heian period if not earlier, and they could qualify as manga under some standards. Under other definitions, the origin of manga was likely in the 18th century, but regardless of what definition you use, it seems likely that the first pornographic manga was quite early in the history of manga and probably not known today. For anime, the question is somewhat more tractable.

Answer (score 11):

The history of Japanese hentai manga is very, very old.

For example, [The Dream of the Fisherman's Wife](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dream_of_the_Fisherman%27s_Wife) (NSFW) was drawn in 1814.
The work is also known as the earliest [tentacle erotica](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tentacle_erotica).
In 1722, the government created a law to ban hentai manga.
This means hentai manga had already been known in public.

For Japanese hentai anime, [Wikipedia entry](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%A2%E3%83%80%E3%83%AB%E3%83%88%E3%82%A2%E3%83%8B%E3%83%A1) says Suzumi-fune (1932) is oldest hentai anime.
But well-known oldest hentai anime is the [Cream Lemon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cream_Lemon) series.
This series was ranked in the best-seller video list (which contains non-adult videos.)

Answer (score 2):

This is just additional information with regards to the previous answer.

The first hentai OVA is credited to *Lolita Anime*, which was first released in February 21, 1984, not to *Cream Lemon*, which was first released in August 11, 1984, although both series are one of the earliest to be released. Due to its sensitive nature, you would have a hard time finding a copy of *Lolita Anime* legally, because as described in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lolita_Anime),

> Containing eight episodes, the series focused on underage sex and rape, and included one episode containing BDSM bondage.

*Urotsukidōji*, on the other hand, was [the first hentai film brought to American viewers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hentai#Origin_of_erotic_anime).

> Often cited for creating the hentai and tentacle rape genres, it contains extreme depictions of violence and monster sex.